# SQl-queries run twice in Heroku NodeJS

Tags: node.js, heroku

Currently I have deployed my website on Heroku with NodeJS.

I came across a weird problem: some SQL-queries are executed twice on mobile, while I don't have this problem on any desktop. So to test if this really was the case, I did a `console.log` after every database query. In the `heroku log` I saw that SQL-queries via my mobile were executed twice.

As you can see below, the request is about if you already follow someone. This request has a lot of nested SQL-queries. I don't really know how to properly structure it and therefore it is possible that the problem lies within that. A string is returned which says something about the new relation between you and the user you're trying to follow/unfollow.

So what I'm trying to do:

1. Check if you follow the person. If this is the case, unfollow the user. Return.
2. Then, check if the user has a public or private account. If he/she has a public account, you can directly follow the person. Return.
3. After that, check if you already try to follow the user with a lock. If this is the case, remove the request. Return.
4. If (3) is not the case, make a request. Return.

When I make this request on my computer, I looked at the `heroku logs` which showed the following:

```
2018-03-31T18:13:18.182665+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 1
2018-03-31T18:13:18.203767+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 3
2018-03-31T18:13:18.204511+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /user/follow 200 55.619 ms - 8
2018-03-31T18:13:18.227543+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 4
```

However, when I did the exact same thing on my mobile, this was showed:

```
2018-03-31T18:16:24.776125+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 1
2018-03-31T18:16:24.786991+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 1
2018-03-31T18:16:24.793902+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 3
2018-03-31T18:16:24.794795+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /user/follow 200 54.334 ms - 8
2018-03-31T18:16:24.802526+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 3
2018-03-31T18:16:24.803279+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /user/follow 200 46.972 ms - 8
2018-03-31T18:16:24.816062+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 4
2018-03-31T18:16:24.821743+00:00 app[web.1]: execution 4
```

To make it clear which SQL-statement executed, I made a `console.log` for each of them with a different name. ('execution1', 'execution2', etc.).

```
// Check the relationship between the user and the search-user
router.post('/follow', function(req, res, next) {

  // Check if the user is logged in
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return;
  }

  // Create connection with database
  pool.getConnection(function (err, database) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Check if you already follow the user
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Followers WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.session.user) + " AND following = " + mysql.escape(req.session.userSearch);

    database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
      console.log("execution 1");
      if (err) throw err;

      // You follow the user if the if-statement is true
      if (result.length != 0) {

        // Unfollow the person
        var sql = "DELETE FROM Followers WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.session.user) + " AND following = " + mysql.escape(req.session.userSearch);

        database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
          console.log("execution 2");
          if (err) throw err;
          database.release();
        });
        return res.send("FOLLOW");
      };

      // Check if the person has a lock on its account
      var sql = "SELECT private FROM Users WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.session.userSearch);

      database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
        console.log("execution 3");
        if (err) throw err;

        // If the account is public, then the if-statement below is true
        if (result[0].private == "0") {

          // Follow if the account is not private
          var sql = "INSERT INTO Followers (user, following) VALUES (" + mysql.escape(req.session.user) + ", " + mysql.escape(req.session.userSearch) + ")";

          database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
            console.log("execution 4");
            if (err) throw err;
            database.release();
          });
          return res.send("UNFOLLOW");
        }

        // Prepare data
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM PendingFollowers WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.session.user) + " AND following = " + mysql.escape(req.session.userSearch);

        database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
          console.log("execution 5");
          if (err) throw err;

          // Check if you already try to follow the person
          if (result.length == "1") {

            // Remove the request
            var sql = "DELETE FROM PendingFollowers WHERE user = " + mysql.escape(req.session.user) + " AND following = " + mysql.escape(req.session.userSearch);

            database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
              console.log("execution 6");
              if (err) throw err;
              database.release();
            });
            return res.send("FOLLOW");
          }

          // Follow and put it in pending
          var sql = "INSERT INTO PendingFollowers (user, following) VALUES (" + mysql.escape(req.session.user) + ", " + mysql.escape(req.session.userSearch) + ")";

          database.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
            console.log("execution 7");
            if (err) throw err;
            database.release();

            return res.send("REQUESTED");
          });
        });
      });
    })
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

HTML:

```
<button class="buttonFollow" ng-click="follow()"> {{ status }} </button>
```

AngularJS:

```
// Status follower
$http.get('/user/status').
then(function(res) {
    $scope.status = res.data;
});

// Follow someone
$scope.follow = function() {
  $http.post('/user/follow').
    then(function(res) {
      $scope.status = res.data;
      $http.get('/user/informationFollower').
        then(function(res){
          $scope.following = res.data[0].following;
          $scope.followers = res.data[0].followers;
        });
   });
};
```

The HTML/AngularJS above is from the page of the user you want to follow. So when the follow-request is done, the number of followers/following of the targeted user will be updated. When I try to follow someone via my computer, the number is incremented with 1 (which is OK). But via my phone, it is incremented with 2. It created a duplicate follow-row in my database on table `Followers`, but the `id` is not the same.

Comment: Now I read my post, I get it that my question gives a arrogant impression. It was meant to ask whether anyone has ever experienced something similair.  I’ll update my question and thank you for giving this feedback.

Comment: Where do POST requests to `/follow` come from?

Comment: Just updated my post at the EDIT-section.